# Get User IP in an ASP .Net Core 2.0 running in a Docker

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose, asp.net-core-2.0

I try to get the user IP in an Asp.Net Core 2.0 web application. This app run in a Docker container.
For test purpose, I’ve start a new web api project and just add this code in the top of Startup Configure methode.

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
{
    try
    {
        StringBuilder requestBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        var remoteIp = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
        string remoteIpstring = remoteIp != null ? remoteIp.ToString() : "-";
        requestBuilder.Append(string.Format("remoteIp={0}\n", remoteIpstring));

        string remotePort = context.Connection.RemotePort.ToString();
        requestBuilder.Append(string.Format("remotePort={0}\n", remotePort));

        var serverIp = context.Connection.LocalIpAddress;
        string serverIpstring = serverIp != null ? serverIp.ToString() : "-";
        requestBuilder.Append(string.Format("serverIp={0}\n", serverIpstring));

        string serverPort = context.Connection.LocalPort.ToString();
        requestBuilder.Append(string.Format("serverPort={0}\n", serverPort));

        foreach (string key in context.Request.Headers.Keys)
        {
            string value = context.Request.Headers[key];
            requestBuilder.Append(string.Format("{0}={1}\n", key, value));
        }

        await context.Response.WriteAsync(requestBuilder.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
});
```

I don’t know why, but when I retrieve the RemoteIpAddress I got the IP of the Docker’s network gateway. And when I retrieve the LocalIpAddress I got the Docker’s network IPAddress.

How can I get the real IP of user ?

Answer (score 3):

From headers like X-Forwarded-For. But for that you will need a mechanism for applying them to the request like proxy for example.
Then you simply ask for the header and extract the value

Below is an example config for nginx as proxy:

```
     location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

Comment: So I can not do it without a reverse proxy ?

Comment: Probably there is another way, but this approach is closer to the real-world situation when the client is behind a proxy and you need the IP of the client, not the one of the proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

After a long fight with ASP.Net Core and the ForwardedHeadersMiddleware, I’ve finally understood why I can’t get the real user/client IP.
When we use the ForwardedHeadersMiddleware in a container and behind a reverse proxy, we must define the IPs of the Gateway and Network ([see this issue on Github for more information](https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/issues/242)).

I don’t want to bother defining these two IPs that I don’t know, because they where setup when the container started.
So I forked the original ForwardedHeadersMiddleware and disabled the behaviour that caused problems.
I created a library with these changes https://www.nuget.org/packages/GST.Library.Middleware.HttpOverrides.

Hope that Microsoft will resolve this issue.